# How to revalue certain data points in R?

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to revalue the data points for one of the variables in the dataset I am working with.

The variable assigns race. Instead of listing out the race as the data point, it is a number. I am trying the revalue the number so that it states the corresponding race.

```
library(plyr)
as.character(data$MRACEHISP)
nat2015p01_new2020$mothersrace <- revalue(data$MRACEHISP, c("1"="WHITE", "2" = "BLACK", "3" = "AIAN", "4"="ASIAN", "5" = "NHOPI", "6" = "MULTIPLE", "7" = "HISPANICE", "8" = "OTHER" ))
```

I keep getting the following error:
Error in revalue(nat2015p01_new2020$MRACEHISP, c(`1` = "WHITE", `2` = "BLACK", : x is not a factor or a character vector.

I am unsure how to solve this error and go about the problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the character values in data

```
library(plyr)
data$MRACEHISP <- as.character(data$MRACEHISP)
nat2015p01_new2020$mothersrace <- revalue(data$MRACEHISP, c("1"="WHITE", "2" = "BLACK", "3" = "AIAN", "4"="ASIAN", "5" = "NHOPI", "6" = "MULTIPLE", "7" = "HISPANICE", "8" = "OTHER" ))
```

Comment: I tried option 1 and got error: Error in revalue(nat2015p01_new2020$MRACEHISP, c(1 = "WHITE", 2 = "BLACK", : x is not a factor or a character vector. Now I just tried option 2 and got error: Error: unexpected '=' in "nat2015p01_new2020$mothersrace <- revalue(nat2015p01_new2020$MRACEHISP, c(1=". Is there any other method?

Comment: Is it intentional that you use two different dataframes in option 1 (data and nat2015p01_new2020?)

Comment: that is my mistake, they are all the same dataframe, I just forgot to change it when typing in the question. In my R, it is the same data frame.

Comment: Then, if you have written data$MRACEHISP <- as.character(data$MRACEHISP) with the right dataframe before the revalue line, it should work. Either you have misspelled something, or there something wrong with your data. Can you tell what is the output of typeof(data$MRACEHISP) before and after the as.character line